# What if light didn't decay by a square law, but instead by an INVERSE square?

Tags: science-fiction, light, electromagnetism

I want to build a character that can control a light source's brightness in different ways. I want to see if instead of proportional to $1/r^2$, my light and darkness controlling character could make it proportional to $r^2$?

Comment: The problem is that light is tied into fundamental physics at a very intricate level. You might check out [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28958). That's about inverse linear rather than direct square, but it should give an idea of what kinds of physics changes would happen. It would be profoundly weird.

Comment: Also worth noting; "light" is just a section of the electromagnetic spectrum.  I suspect that control over the "brightness" of x-ray or gamma sources would be far more useful than visible light.

Comment: So you want a light that grows stronger as it propagates?

Comment: @L.Dutch Now that would be a useful super-power. Effectively amplifying low-light sources into blindingly bright ones at a distance.

Comment: @Cadence I dont think that would apply. The question mentioned is about a whole universe rather than a local magic phenomenon caused by the hero (villain?). As the control is magic, the OP could simply ignore the consequences for local space or still apply the conservation of energy law by having energy escape diffferently based on the magic of controlling light.

Comment: I don't get what the question is. If you have a character that can make butter green, you've got green butter.

Comment: So to burn your opponent to a crisp, you just convert the light coming from the sun to r^2?  Or, if you want to wipe out life on the planet, you convert the light coming from a distant star..

Comment: Sorry. What I mean here is change the way light decays from a source. For example, when bulb shines my character can make the light towards the source weaker and FROM the sounds stronger. Change the amount of light and darkness in an area. I do agree with some of the comments above.

Comment: Yes light that grows stronger as it propagates

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is roughly what happens in so called gaining medium.

Normally, as light propagates in any medium, gets attenuated according to the law $I(x)=I_0e^{-\alpha x}$, where $\alpha$ is called absorption coefficient.

In a gaining medium $\alpha$ is negative, resulting in light being amplified as it travels through the medium. This is used in laser cavities and light amplifiers.

To generate a gaining medium one needs to achieve population inversion in the medium, or, in layman terms, there need to be more excited than neutral atoms in that medium. I.e. RF excited CO2 can act as amplifier for infrared light.

So, if your guy is able to induce inversion population, he can achieve what you want. Oh, mind that the exponential grows even more than the square...

Comment: Yes. This kinda answers it. I want my photokinetic character to be able change it from 1/r to 1/r, 1/r-² or even 1/r-³. The character I'm building can use light for both illusory and destructive effects. What I meant by inverse square was the opposite of how light usually decays from a source.

Comment: @shawnny321, please clarify it in your question. As you see, it has been put on hold for this